# How do I replace text in a google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet I am using for a website. I have various headers: city, description1, description 2, type1, desc1, etc.
In the type1 header, I am using it as a header then the desc1 will be the description for that header on the website.

Description 1 needs to be personalized to the city so I need to replace the city for each relevant row. Is there a way to automate this using a macro? If so, how would I do so? I have very limited developer knowledge so thanks for your help!

Edit:

Sorry about that, I forgot to include it.

Here is a sample sheet with the basics. I removed description, description two and the Bartenders columns which are already filled out in the live sheet.

I need Desc1 through Desc6 columns to keep the text but replace the [city] text with the city column in the same row. I have done the first row, Sioux Falls City as an example. This isn't the exact text in the columns but I edited it for this example. Let me know if you need further clarification or information. Thanks again, your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: As player0 has said please try to provide a sample sheet, that we can copy and understand your problem? Also a little clarification would be nice. Refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry guys, edited to include the example sheet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to a google support user found here:
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/26944892?hl=en

Basically, I added a new sheet and used this formula in cell A1

=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!A:R, "[city]", Sheet1!A:A))

Comment: Remember to accept your own question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer